# php mysql - echo clear division after 3rd result

Tags: php, mysql, css

I echo results in DESC order from MySQL table with while loop. I've pagination system implemented already and its size is 9 records per page. The problem is, that if I do:

```
// ECHO CSS BREAK
if($row['id'] % 3 == 0){
    echo '<li class="clear"></li>';
}

// SHOW VIDEOS
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<li>...echo code...</li>';
    // problem = implement that echo css break in ASC order
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop variable, e.g.

```
$i = 0;
```

Then instead of

```
if ($row['id'] % 3 == 0) {
```

do

```
if (++$i % 3 === 0) {
```

This makes sure it always happens are the third [sixth, ninth, ...] time.
You may want to get arbitrary rows from the database at another point in time, or shuffle the results -- relying on row IDs is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking to implement?

```
// SHOW VIDEOS
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($row['id'] % 3 == 0){
        echo '<li>...echo code...</li>';
        echo '<li class="clear"></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li>...echo code...</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: @flo also makes a good point as a constant would be more reliable, as the ID may not be consecutive.

Comment: Thanks! But that's code for DESC order. My problem is that I need to convert order from DESC to ASC.